# Is it possible to change the file path using a hex Editor?

Tags: windows, path, attributes, hex, editor

I am in the middle of a discussion with a friend of mine. The question is, if you can edit a (For example jpg) file so that windows opens another (jpg) file by using a hex Editor.
So basically you have a file saved on your desktop. Now if you open this file, another file with the same extension should open. I did not found anything on the internet so hopefully someome here can answer the question.

Thanks in advance 
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. Path information is not stored in file, but in storage system metadata, for example:

Windows uses NFTS file system: In NTFS, all file, directory and metafile data—file name, creation date, access permissions (by the use of access control lists), and size—are stored as metadata in the Master File Table (MFT) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles)

Here is link to good answer on how to access metadata on different filesystems: [Where filesystems store their file metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481917/where-filesystems-store-their-file-metadata)

What you can do thought is to disguise .exe file as jpg file, and make this .exe file open another, real jpg file:
https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/2me7qn/hide_exe_within_a_jpg_or_any_other_extension/

Comment: Thank you! I did not unterstand where these file tables are stored. I do not want to change the extension either. Only the path.

Comment: So is there a way to edit the path of a file when this file is stored on an external FAT32 USB drive?

Comment: Yes, and it is called "move the file". I thing you won't find better source than this: http://repo.hackerzvoice.net/depot_madchat/coding/filesystems/sitania.pdf look at page 11